# MsiTran Error 110

Tags: installation, windows-installer, transform

I'm trying to apply a transform to my msi file. I've created the transform using Orca (new transform->generate transform) and when I run it with MsiTrans I get Error 110. Error Opening Database.

Does anyone know what this is or how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MsiTrans never did work for me. I couldn't solve the Error 110.

Instead, I used the visual basic script `WiUseXfm.vbs` which takes 2 arguments (the msi and the mst) and applies the the transform to the msi.

`WiUseXfm.vbs` can be found in the sample scripts in the install directory for Microsoft SDK which for me was `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\v7.0\Samples\sysmgmt\msi\scripts`

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue so I think that you need to generate a new Universal Transform:

See: https://www.itninja.com/question/create-generic-mst

In orca file->new 
Transform Menu -> new transform
Add your tables, rows, etc.
Apply transform and save it somewhere