# brackets-shell MsiTran.exe error

Tags: wix, brackets-shell

Whe I build my installer I get this error with `brackets-win-install-build.xml` on line 143 - exec returned 1.

**brackets-win-install-build.xml**

```
26  : <property name="msitran.cmd" value="${wix.base}/bin/MsiTran.exe"/>
      {...}
143 : <exec  executable='"${msitran.cmd}"' failonerror='true'>
144 :     <arg line="-g '${product.fullname}.msi' brackets_fr-fr.msi fr-fr.mst"/>
145 : </exec>
```

I do have MsiTran.exe, WiLangId.vbs and WiSubStg.vbs in my WiX 3.5 bin folder.

**EDIT for @Iain Ballard**

Tried changing '/' by '\' still the same error.

But I tried to rue msiTran from the command prompt and this is what I got :

[image]

Comment: Try changing those '/' into '\'. Otherwise, what happens if you run the command from a normal command line in the Wix build current directory? (i.e. `cd C:\my\project\` ; `C:\wixbase\bin\MsiTran.exe -g ...`)

Comment: Edited my answer with the results.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I expected the entire command you are trying to run: `C:\WiX_3.5\bin\MsiTran.exe -g 'MYPRODCUT.msi' brackets_fr-fr.msi fr-fr.mst`

Comment: Error opening base database...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've run into a well known problem. Ensure the 'Orca' tools is closed. Try running as an administrator.
Try

```
msitran.exe -a fr-fr.mst MYPRODCUT.msi
```

to do the transform in place.

There is an alternative solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205628/msitran-error-110)